# Расширение поля продуктов JSON API МойСклад (Products Expand Attributes)

Tags: мойсклад-api

Могу ли я расширить поле attributes на ещё 1 уровень в запросе продукта? Я бы хотел получить комментарий, помимо имени в поле value. Существует ли способ получить это поле через expand?

Или мне придётся делать дополнительный запрос/создавать дополнительный аттрибут с данными, чтобы я мог получать его с обычным запросом?

UPD:
[image: Запрос после использования expand=attributes.value]

UPD2: Справочники дополнительные и как видно из скриншота у меня несколько аттрибутов в объекте, но ни один из них не приходит расширенным.

Comment: Вам помог ответ? Если да, отметьте его, пожалуйста, как верный.

Answer (score 1):

При запросе укажите ?expand=attributes.value, тогда поле value дополнительного поля вернется полностью (не только мета и имя).

`https://online.moysklad.ru/api/remap/1.1/entity/product/ade4468e-4409-11e9-ac12-000d000000c0?expand=attributes.value`

В ответе будет

```
"attributes": [
    {
        "meta": {
            "href": "https://online.moysklad.ru/api/remap/1.1/entity/product/metadata/attributes/8b0bfb6c-459e-11e9-ac12-000d0000001f",
            "type": "attributemetadata",
            "mediaType": "application/json"
        },
        "id": "8b0bfb6c-459e-11e9-ac12-000d0000001f",
        "name": "Справочник",
        "type": "customentity",
        "value": {
            "meta": {
                "href": "https://online.moysklad.ru/api/remap/1.1/entity/customentity/906e24fb-459d-11e9-ac12-000d00000018/795f38c1-459e-11e9-ac12-000d0000001c",
                "metadataHref": "https://online.moysklad.ru/api/remap/1.1/entity/companysettings/metadata/customEntities/906e24fb-459d-11e9-ac12-000d00000018",
                "type": "customentity",
                "mediaType": "application/json",
                "uuidHref": "https://online.moysklad.ru/app/#custom_906e24fb-459d-11e9-ac12-000d00000018/edit?id=795f38c1-459e-11e9-ac12-000d0000001c"
            },
            "id": "795f38c1-459e-11e9-ac12-000d0000001c",
            "accountId": "56c92164-40d9-11e9-ac12-000a00000001",
            "updated": "2019-03-13 17:44:15",
            "name": "Единица",
            "description": "Описание единицы",
            "externalCode": "O86DR1gHha9dNwBS-jW253"
        }
    }
]
```

Comment: Прошу прощения, так и сделал, однако ответ по прежнему такой же. Возможно дело в том, что в справочнике нет кодов? Или в том, что аттрибутов у меня несколько? Так или иначе ответ отличается.

Comment: Влияет ли то, что справочник дополнительный на expand?

Comment: Возможно вы используете id товара, который виден в основном интерфейсе. В АПИ id товаров отличаются. В этом случае вы получаете редирект по id, используемому в АПИ. Но при этом теряются параметры запроса и вы получаете товар без expand. 
Если это так, то это будет видно в ответе - в поле id будет не такое значение, как в запросе.